# Items don't turn out of stock when qty is 0

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, stock, quantity

I am using magento community 1.7.0.2
I checked in System / Configurations / Catalog / Inventory
"Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock' is set to 0
However I have noticed that all of the products that have been sold out have quantity 0 and status 'in stock'. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Check your system configuration for values set at different store/website levels that might override your global settings.

Check your individual products for configuration that might override your system configuration levels.

Try setting a quantity to 1, purchasing a product, and checking is things are marked out of stock. (i.e. the products you see may have been explicitly set to be in stock with a quantity of 0 before you made your change.  If this is the case and the system is otherwise behaving, I'd try setting those products to be out of stock manually)

Comment: If I check a product and what I see in inventory tab is

Manage Stock is Yes
tick on  Use Config Settings 
Enable Qty Increments is No
tick on  Use Config Settings
Stock Availability is in stock

obviously it will be deadly time consuming to just change stock availability for 1000 items, does any of above says that anything was done wrong, when the item was created?

Comment: @AntK I'd start by determining if your system actually has a bug that doesn't switch items over to out of stock when they turn to zero.  If there's not a bug, then you can address how to fix items with 0 availability.  The Stock Configuration objects are sufficiently complex that giving an pat answer remotely is impossible.

Comment: I've noticed that it works with simple products. But it doesn't with configurable products. Even if all simple ones within the configurable are with qty 0 and inventory out of stock, the configurable inventory is still in stock. This is what causes all the trouble